# windows c++ DNS lookups

Tags: c++, windows, dns

I have a windows C++ application (mingw, but I guess it doesn't matter). I need to do very occasional obscure types of DNS lookups, such as TXT and AXFR.

The best I can do at the moment is using gethostbyname in winsock, but that doesn't support the above types :(. Does anyone know of a nice library that runs on win32 for DNS lookups?

thanks

thn

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `libunbound` which is included in the source distribution of the [`Unbound`](http://www.unbound.net/) recursive DNS server.

It's a full-feature recursive resolver bundled in a library.  Alternatively the same group has a generic DNS library with a stub resolver called [`ldns`](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/).

p.s. are you sure `mingw` doesn't support the UNIX standard `libresolv`?  Check for a function called `res_query`.

Comment: I've been reading the ldns source today, which led me to conclude that unbound is a much better suggestion, so I decided to remove my answer. +1 from me ;-)

Comment: Seriously have **anybody** **ever** compiled _unbound_ on a Windows PC with MingW. It does not seem to work. I have wasted **days** trying and could not get the _configure_ to complete its work. I used the latest MingW and the latest unbound source and installed the latest _openssl_ and _expat_ when it did not found those. The executables are working but there seemingly is no way to make them. I'm starting to suspect that they are only cross compiled from Linux.

Comment: @mg30rg did you try asking NL.net labs?  In my experience they're pretty helpful.

Comment: @Alnitak - No I have not tried that yet. You see, I'm a windows guy and I did not want to bee seem as a moron for forgetting something elemental. But I will try it now since I hawe no other choices left. Thanks for the suggestion!